# Why winform control size can't change according to my input value

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

i am buling a project with vs2022 winform on .net-framework4.8.
when i add a label(any control) control to windows form,i can cange control side by mouse as i like,it working fine.but if i change side by change size directly,then the return size didn't change according to my input value.
for example, my original size is 267x36
if i want to change height to 30, the return value become 223x25, and the size and location on windows form also abnormal,looks like both change automatic.
even i try to select two control, and use vs2022 button "make them same side",the second control also return a wrong size.enter image description here
i am using a laptop with 150% scaling and screen resolution 2560x1600

picture1,original size
picture2,return size[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZsxZ.png)
picture3,windows form [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8q7P.png)

Comment: A control you can lock/unlock the ratio of height and width (the aspect ratio).  Check to se if object has aspect ration locked = true.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `AutoSize` is set to `true` by default for labels. Disabling `AutoSize` will let you control the size manually.

Comment: i try already ,nothing about Autosize. I think problem is because i have two monitor with difference resolution and scaling.

Comment: Try setting the scale to 100%. Does that work?